# Ruby wrong number of arguments in class instantitation

Tags: ruby, class, object

I am trying to make a battleship game in Ruby, but when I try to create an instance of the game board, I get "wrong number of arguments, 0 for 1". I dont see where I am going wrong as the initialize definition clearly accepts arguments.

```
class Board

  attr_reader :grid, :default_grid

  def intitalize(grid = self.class.default_grid, random = false)
    @grid = grid
    make_random_board if random
  end

  def self.default_grid
    grid = Array.new(10){Array.new(10)}
  end

  def count
    grid.flatten.count{|x| x == :s}
  end

  def self.random
    self.new(self.default_grid, true)
  end

  def empty?(position = nil)
    return true if position.nil?
    else
    false
  end

  def full?
    grid.flatten.none?(&:nil?)
  end

  def place_random_ship
      if full? 
        raise "error, board is full"
      end

      space = [rand(grid.length),rand(grid.length)] 
        until empty?(space)
          space = [rand(grid.length),rand(grid.length)]
        end
      self[space] = :s
  end

  def make_random_board(count = 10)
    count.times do
      place_random_ship
    end
  end

end

emptygrid = Array.new(2){Array.new(2)}
myGame = Board.new(emptygrid)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. You should be using `initialize` instead of `intitalize`

And i believe the error you might have been getting would be `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`

Which is because of your typo, the default class `initialize` method was used, which doesn't take in any arguments.

And something unrelated that i noticed in your code. You have defined a method named `count` and use variables named `count`. This is a code smell and i would suggest naming the method differently, because down the line, this might cause some bugs, that you might find hard to debug.